# Twilio - Human / Non Human / Robot detection (IfMachine parameter)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, twilio

Twilio based human/non human detection - I'm trying to detect if a call has been picked up by a human or robot via the code as shown below

```
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("From", myfromnumber);
params.put("To", tonumber);
params.put("Url", Url);
params.put("Method", "POST");
params.put("IfMachine", "Continue");

CallFactory callFactory = account.getCallFactory();
Call call = callFactory.create(params);
out.println("<p>Call status: " + call.getStatus() + "</p>");

if (machine.equals(request.getParameter("AnsweredBy")){
    System.out.println("Its machine");
} else{
    System.out.println("Not Machine");
};
```

For some reason the `request.getParameter("AnsweredBy")` is always coming as NULL, if i understand it should be either "machine" or "human".

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `AnsweredBy` parameter is passed along in a webhook request that is made *after* a call is created through the REST API ([check the docs here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#handling-outcomes-answering-machines)).  In this case, you have created `call` object with the correct `IfMachine` parameter, so that is half the battle.

Then, in a separate (Servlet?) request handler for `Url`, you would have access to the `request.getParameter("AnsweredBy")`.  If this is not defined in that scenario, we would need to look at your actual code, outside the snippet above.

Hope this is helpful,
-Kevin